# How do I add a button to the InAppSettingsKit setting view (iPhone/iPad)?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, settings, inappsettingskit

I have been looking at the sample app provided by InAppSettingsKit and I noticed the use of a couple of buttons:

[image]

I would like to integrate a single red button in my app called reset, however I'm not sure how to do it. I've had a look at the code in the sample app and I'm a bit lost with it all. Please could someone help me out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After spending a while searching through all the code and plists I managed to find the answer to my question. For those who are interested what you need to do is the following:

1. Add a row to your Root.plist file with the Type set to `IASKButtonSpecifier`.
2. Set the Identifier on this row as something useful e.g. 'myButton1'.
3. Add the following delegate method to the viewController you loaded the InAppSettingsKit from:

   ```
   - (void)settingsViewController:(IASKAppSettingsViewController*)sender buttonTappedForKey:(NSString*)key 
   {
       if ([key isEqualToString:@"myButton1"]) 
       {
          // Do some actions...
       }
   }
   ```

It's worth noting that the key is equal to the identifier you set in the Root.plist.

The only thing I haven't worked out yet is how to change the colour of the button; however I suspect this may be possible by overriding a method.

Comment: i don't able to add Button, whats wrong with this... i twicced checked my code.

Comment: Note that method has been deprecated; use this instead: `- (void)settingsViewController:(IASKAppSettingsViewController*)sender buttonTappedForSpecifier:(IASKSpecifier*)specifier`

Comment: One thing you did not mention took me a while to figure out - don't forget to set `self.delegate = self` once the controller is initialised if you want to get that delegate method called! As of v2.9 no delegate is set

Comment: Swift version: `func settingsViewController(_ settingsViewController: IASKAppSettingsViewController,
                                buttonTappedFor specifier: IASKSpecifier) {}`

Answer (score 5):

Great that you already found part of the solution. To customize the look, you should create a custom view using the `IASKCustomViewSpecifier` documented on http://www.inappsettingskit.com/. The yellow icon for instance is making use of this. In your case, you could return an instance of UIButton with a red background color (or a custom background image).

In this case, you don't need the buttonTappedForKey method to get the tap event but configure the target/action of your button as usual.