# Swift: How do I add a button to the InAppSettingsKit setting view (iPhone/iPad)?

Tags: ios, swift, inappsettingskit

I followed the instructions in "[How do I add a button to the InAppSettingsKit setting view (iPhone/iPad)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848805/how-do-i-add-a-button-to-the-inappsettingskit-setting-view-iphone-ipad)" I have the button appearing in the settings screen.
However, I can't receive input when clicked.
my bridge header:

```
#include <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "InAppSettingsKit/IASKViewController.h"
#import "InAppSettingsKit/IASKAppSettingsViewController.h"
#import "InAppSettingsKit/IASKSpecifier.h"
#import "InAppSettingsKit/IASKSettingsReader.h"
```

my class:

```
class settingsViewController: IASKAppSettingsViewController
{
    func settingsViewController(sender: IASKAppSettingsViewController, buttonTappedForSpecifier specifier: IASKSpecifier)
    {
        println("click")
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set the delegate in your `settingsViewController`? Btw, the convention is to start class names with capital letters and it's recommended to add a prefix such as `XYZSettingsViewController`.

Comment: how do I "set a delegate"

Comment: Apparently you already found that out. I edited your answer to better reflect what you're doing in the code.

Answer (score 4):

To catch the button tap, set the delegate to receive callbacks:

```
import UIKit;
class settingsViewController: IASKAppSettingsViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        self.delegate = self
    }
    func settingsViewController(sender: AnyObject, buttonTappedForKey key: String)
    {
         println("click \(key)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to add `IASKSettingsDelegate` and implement `func settingsViewControllerDidEnd(_ sender:IASKAppSettingsViewController)` to make the button work (in XCode 8.2.1 and Swift 3)